# Hibernate performs a Delete on a Select

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I'm facing a problem with Hibernate.
My current project is a little game. In this game you have a **Board** which has many **Fields** each with a **Token**.
I can make a select on an empty database without any problems but if I put one object into it (saving works without any exceptions and after it the database values looks good) I'm getting exceptions.
The interesting part in the Board class:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKey(name = "point")
public Map<Point, Field> getGameMatrix() {
     return gameMatrix;
}
```

My query for getting the boards:

```
return getHibernateTemplate().loadAll(Board.class);
```

The log now comes up with this:

> Hibernate: select this_.id as id0_2_,
>   this_.uniqueClassName as
>   uniqueCl3_0_2_, this_.borderDimension
>   as borderDi4_0_2_, this_.dimension as
>   dimension0_2_, this_.TYPE as TYPE0_2_,
>   gamematrix2_.Board_id as Board1_4_,
>   field3_.id as gameMatrix2_4_, (select
>   a11.point from Field a11 where
>   a11.id=gamematrix2_.gameMatrix_id) as
>   formula0_4_, field3_.id as id1_0_,
>   field3_.point as point1_0_,
>   field3_.token_id as token3_1_0_,
>   token4_.id as id2_1_, token4_.name as
>   name2_1_, token4_.uniqueClassName as
>   uniqueCl4_2_1_, token4_.TYPE as
>   TYPE2_1_ from Board this_ left outer
>   join Board_Field gamematrix2_ on
>   this_.id=gamematrix2_.Board_id left
>   outer join Field field3_ on
>   gamematrix2_.gameMatrix_id=field3_.id
>   left outer join Token token4_ on
>   field3_.token_id=token4_.id

Until there it looks good, but then Hibernate does the following:

```
Hibernate: delete from Board_Field where Board_id=?  
Hibernate: insert into Board_Field (Board_id, gameMatrix_id) values (?, ?)
```

And I got this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   object references an unsaved transient
>   instance - save the transient instance
>   before flushing: Field; nested
>   exception is
>   org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:
>   object references an unsaved transient
>   instance - save the transient instance
>   before flushing: Field

I'm not understanding why it makes the delete statement.
Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Did the earlier transaction close properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workmate of mine had a similar problem. He's not now but the thing was related to database integrity.

It seems Hibernate had more constraints defined that the database. When it loaded some data, Hibernate saw that some record in the database must not exist, and tried to delete it.

Try to check if some should-be-but-not-defined foreign key is being violated and try to make consistent the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `cascade` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@MapKey(name = "point")
public Map<Point, Field> getGameMatrix() {
     return gameMatrix;
}
```

And you also need to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` for `Point` and `Field` - let your IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ) generate them for you, using their business key (i.e. not their auto-generated ID)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are adding a Field object to the collection of Fields in the Board class, but you have to persist the new Field object first (you are probably new'ing it)

Hence the exception message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Field

Comment: I'm doing this,I don't get the exception when I want to save a board. Saving boards works and the values in the database are fine. I'm getting the exception when I want select all boards.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue quite a while ago and although this question is already answered, thought i'd post it here for future reference.

Basically, I encountered the same behaviour when the setter was effectively empty (either because the assignment is not present or is incorrect or there is a business logic in the setter that resulted in it being effectively null).

Guess hibernate first selects and considers the data as persistent (persistence-level-cache) and then when it does a dirty-check it finds that the data has been deleted (because the getter does not return the data since it was never set) and proceeds to fire a delete.

Had posted regarding it [in hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1011603&start=0) too.

Just posting it here for future reference!

Regards
Ravindra